# Populate information from a csv file into a LaTeX document (specifically into the fields/arguments of commands therein)

Tags: moderncv, external-files, datatool, csvsimple, metadata

I have some personal information stored in a plain CSV file `personal_info.csv` in the following format:

#### `personal_info.csv`

```
83 Fancy Avenue,Nowheresville,Gotham City 24061
123 456 7890
someone@xyz.com
```

I need to populate the relevant fields of the below `main.tex` (non-working/mockup) using class `moderncv` with this personal information as shown below.

#### Mock-up (non-working concept) of `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

%% NOT WORKING MOCKUP! (Relevant content to be read from csv file `personal_info.tex`)
\address{\firstfieldofline1}{\secondfieldofline1}{\thirdfieldofline2} 
\phone[mobile]{\firstfieldofline2}
\email{\firstfieldofline3}

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

to produce the desired output `main.pdf` (compiled with `pdflatex`).

[image: desired output with populated fields from csv file]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `readarray` (and `listofitems` included).

First, I employ `readarray` macros

```
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{personalinfo.csv}\myrawdata
```

to take the contents of `personalinfo.csv` and place it into the macro `\myrawdata`, all the while converting end-of-record tokens into `\\`.  Then, with `listofitems` macros,

```
\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*{\mydata}{\myrawdata}
```

I set up a 2-tier parsing of `\myrawdata` and place the result into the array named `\mydata`.  The `\\` token separates the 1st tier items, and the `,` separates the 2nd-tier items within each 1st-tier item.

The syntax of `listofitems` allows the array to be recalled by the indices of the parsing.  Thus `\mydata[1,2]` will extract the tokens of `\myrawdata` that occurred before the 1st `\\` and, within that set of tokens, those that are between the 1st and 2nd `,`.

The MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{personalinfo.csv}
83 Fancy Avenue,Nowheresville,Gotham City 24061
123 456 7890
someone@xyz.com
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{readarray}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}

\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{personalinfo.csv}\myrawdata
\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*{\mydata}{\myrawdata}

\address{\mydata[1,1]}{\mydata[1,2]}{\mydata[1,3]} 
\phone[mobile]{\mydata[2,1]}
\email{\mydata[3,1]}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Quick and dirty `expl3` implementation:

First you load the CSV file with `\LoadCSV{<label>}{<file>}`. This command will open the file and load the contents of the CSV into `<label>`. The contents of the file are read verbatim (all catcodes are `other` (12), except for `space`s (10)).

Then you get a field with `\GetCSV{<label>}{<line>}{<field>}`.

Replacing your mockup code with:

```
\LoadCSV {mycsv} {\jobname.csv}
\address{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{1}}{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{2}}{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{3}} 
\phone[mobile]{\GetCSV{mycsv}{2}{1}}
\email{\GetCSV{mycsv}{3}{1}}
```

it prints:

> [image]

Full code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
83 Fancy Avenue,Nowheresville,Gotham City 24061
123 456 7890
someone@xyz.com
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l__krishna_ior_tmpa
\cs_new:Npn \krishna_csv_load:nn #1 #2
  {
    \cs_if_free:cTF { l__krishna_ #1 _seq }
      { \__krishna_csv_load:nn { l__krishna_ #1 } {#2} }
      { \msg_error:nnn { krishna / csv } { name-used } {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__krishna_csv_load:nn #1 #2
  {
    \ior_open:Nn \l__krishna_ior_tmpa {#2}
    \seq_new:c { #1 _seq }
    \exp_args:Nc
      \__krishna_csv_read:N { #1 _seq }
    \ior_close:N \l__krishna_ior_tmpa
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__krishna_csv_read:N #1
  {
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l__krishna_ior_tmpa
      { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 {##1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \krishna_csv_get:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \exp_args:Nf
    \clist_item:nn
      { \seq_item:cn { l__krishna_ #1 _seq } {#2} }
      {#3}
  }
\msg_new:nnn { krishna / csv } { name-used }
  { The~CSV~name~`#1'~is~already~taken }
\cs_new_eq:NN \LoadCSV \krishna_csv_load:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \GetCSV \krishna_csv_get:nnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\LoadCSV {mycsv} {\jobname.csv}
\address{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{1}}{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{2}}{\GetCSV{mycsv}{1}{3}} 
\phone[mobile]{\GetCSV{mycsv}{2}{1}}
\email{\GetCSV{mycsv}{3}{1}}

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

But @Mensch's idea of a `.tex` file with definitions is *far* simpler :)

Answer (score 10):

Let us say we have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

Now move the personal data into a new file `mydata.tex`:

```
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}
```

After that you can use the new code (simply used `\input` instead the original personal datas):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\input{mydata.tex} % <===========================================

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

There are no differences in the both resulting pdfs ...

Post the shown `mydata.tex` with the code for the cv on github and keep a copy of `mydata.tex` for your own purpose, of course filled with your real informations for a real cv ...