# Get the single data from .csv file using latex

Tags: csvsimple

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,y
-10,96.5
-5,93.5
6,93.5
10,97
\end{filecontents*}
```

Assume that I have a data.csv file. I need one element of it, e.g., `$x=-10$`. However, I want to get -10 from the file directly instead of editing by hand. How can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You want to pick `y` where `x=-10` or do you want to pick `x` on row 1?

Comment: I wan to pick the value of x or value of y I need. Yes. e.g., I want to pick x on row 1.

Comment: Then my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474404/134574) should do what you want