# input specific elements from csv

Tags: input, csv

I have a csv table and I want to input specific cells.
For instance, my csv is project.csv:

```
       , obj, resources, wp
task1.1, 1  ,   2k     , 1
task2.1, 2  ,   3k     , 2 
task3.1, 3  ,   4k     , 3
```

Ideally, I would like to input specific elements from it, for instance by referring to it by its column and row name. For instance:

```
Resources for the first task from Work Package \input{project.csv[task1.1, wp]} are \input{project.csv[task1.1, resources]} USD
```

Comment: Something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474404/134574?

Comment: Are you able to change the CSV so it has a header for the tasks column, like `task`?

Comment: @Phelype,  being able to refer to it using the col/rowname would make it easier, but yes something like that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Werner, yes, I can modify the csv to add headers for all the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool)'s `\DTLfetch{<db name>}{<source col>}{<source val>}{<target col>}` to return the value associated with `<target col>` where `<source col>` is `<source val>` in `<db name>` (it acts like a lookup-up table).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{tasks.csv}
task,obj,resources,wp
task1.1,1,2k,1
task2.1,2,3k,2 
task3.1,3,4k,3
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

% Load the database; later referenced as tasks
\DTLloaddb
  [keys={task,obj,resources,wp}]% <options>
  {tasks}% <db name>
  {tasks.csv}% <filename>

Resources for the first task from Work Package 
\DTLfetch{tasks}{task}{task1.1}{wp} %\input{project.csv[task1.1, wp]} 
are 
\DTLfetch{tasks}{task}{task1.1}{resources} %\input{project.csv[task1.1, resources]} 
USD.

\end{document}
```

Note that spaces in the CSV file are returned, so that'll depend on how you manage spaces within the output (from `\DTLfetch`). I've removed them, since typical CSV exports will exclude them.

Comment: fantastic, easy and simple, thanks!

Comment: Additional related question, if there are multiple matches for a given row/column combination, how can I retrieve them all?  

For instance, if the csv has one extra column (obj) with all its values being the same (1)    


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{tasks.csv}  
task,obj,resources,wp,obj  
task1.1,1,2k,1,1   
task2.1,2,3k,2,1    
task3.1,3,4k,3,1   
\end{filecontents*}   

How can I do something like   

\DTLfetch{tasks}{objective}{1}{task}

Where the output is both tasks  

task1.1, task1.2, task1.3

Comment: @augusto: Not with `\DTLfetch` (which only returns the first occurence/match). You'd have to process the entire database and perform a check for each record if you want to return more than one result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `expl3` implementation from scratch.  Use

```latex
\ReadCSV { <filename> } \command
```

to read the `.csv` file to `<filename>`, and store it to be used in `\command`, then use:

```latex
\command{<row>,<column>}
```

to get the item corresponding to `<row>` and `<column>` (accessed by name).

The `\command` is expandable, so you can safely use it in captions, section headings, etc.

Additionally, you can use

```
\IterateCSVRows \command {<code>}
% and
\IterateCSVCols \command {<code>}
```

to iterate over the rows and columns of the read CSV file.  In the `<code>`, `#1` is the row or column name for the current iteration, so you can use `\command{#1,col}` or `\command{row,#1}` in `<code>`.  If you nest both, the inner command has to use `##1` for the row or column name.  The example below shows how to reconstruct the `.csv` as a table using these commands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{project.csv}
task   , obj, resources, wp
task1.1, 1  ,   2k     , 1
task2.1, 2  ,   3k     , 2
task3.1, 3  ,   4k     , 3
\end{filecontents*}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__augusto_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l__augusto_csv_name_tl
\ior_new:N \l__augusto_csv_ior
\seq_new:N \l__augusto_tmpa_seq
\int_new:N \l__augusto_csv_rows_int
\bool_new:N \l__augusto_csv_read_as_string_bool
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put_if_new:Nnn { cVx }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \augusto_read_csv:NnN #1 #2 #3
  {
    \bool_set_eq:NN \l__augusto_csv_read_as_string_bool #1
    \ior_open:NnTF \l__augusto_csv_ior {#2}
      {
        \cs_if_exist:NTF #3
          { \msg_error:nnn { augusto } { command-exists } {#3} }
          { \exp_args:Nf \__augusto_read_csv:nN { \cs_to_str:N #3 } #3 }
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { augusto } { file-not-found } {#2} }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { augusto } { file-not-found }
  { File~'#1'~not~found. }
\msg_new:nnn { augusto } { command-exists }
  { Command~'#1'~already~defined. }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__augusto_read_csv:nN #1 #2
  {
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand #2 { m }
      { \__augusto_get_csv_item:nn {##1} {#1} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__augusto_csv_name_tl {#1}
    \bool_if:NTF \l__augusto_csv_read_as_string_bool
      { \ior_str_get:NN } { \ior_get:NN }
          \l__augusto_csv_ior \l__augusto_tmpa_tl
    \seq_set_from_clist:NV \l__augusto_tmpa_seq \l__augusto_tmpa_tl
    \seq_pop:NN \l__augusto_tmpa_seq \l__augusto_tmpa_tl
    \seq_new:c { g__augusto_csv_#1_cols_seq }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__augusto_tmpa_seq
      {
        \seq_new:c { g__augusto_csv_#1_##1_seq }
        \seq_gput_right:cn { g__augusto_csv_#1_cols_seq } {##1}
      }
    \prop_new:c { g__augusto_csv_#1_rows_prop }
    \int_zero:N \l__augusto_csv_rows_int
    \bool_if:NTF \l__augusto_csv_read_as_string_bool
      { \ior_str_map_inline:Nn } { \ior_map_inline:Nn }
          \l__augusto_csv_ior
        {
          \int_incr:N \l__augusto_csv_rows_int
          \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__augusto_tmpa_seq { , } {##1}
          \seq_pop:NN \l__augusto_tmpa_seq \l__augusto_tmpa_tl
          \prop_put_if_new:cVx { g__augusto_csv_#1_rows_prop }
            \l__augusto_tmpa_tl { \int_use:N \l__augusto_csv_rows_int }
          \seq_mapthread_function:cNN
            { g__augusto_csv_#1_cols_seq } \l__augusto_tmpa_seq
            \__augusto_add_csv_row:nn
        }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \augusto_map_csv_rows:Nn #1 #2
  { \prop_map_inline:cn { g__augusto_csv_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _rows_prop } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \augusto_map_csv_cols:Nn #1 #2
  { \seq_map_inline:cn { g__augusto_csv_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _cols_seq } {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__augusto_add_csv_row:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_gput_right:cn
      { g__augusto_csv_ \l__augusto_csv_name_tl _#1_seq }
      {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__augusto_get_csv_item:nn #1
  { \__augusto_get_csv_item:wn #1 , \q_nil , \s_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__augusto_get_csv_item:wn #1 , #2 , #3 \s_stop #4
  {
    \quark_if_nil:nTF {#2}
      { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { augusto } { invalid-item } {#4} }
      {
        \exp_args:Nff \__augusto_get_item:nnn
          { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} } {#4}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__augusto_get_item:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \exp_args:Ncc \__augusto_get_item:NNnn
      { g__augusto_csv_#3_#2_seq } { g__augusto_csv_#3_rows_prop }
      {#1} {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__augusto_get_item:NNnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \seq_if_exist:NTF #1
      {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF #2 {#3}
          { \seq_item:Nn #1 { \prop_item:Nn #2 {#3} } }
          { \use_ii:nn }
      }
      { \use_ii:nn }
    \use_none:n
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnn
          { augusto } { invalid-item } {#3,#4}
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { augusto } { invalid-item }
  { Invalid~item~'#1'. }
\NewDocumentCommand \ReadCSV { s m m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \augusto_read_csv:NnN \c_true_bool }
      { \augusto_read_csv:NnN \c_false_bool }
        {#2} #3
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \IterateCSVRows { m +m }
  { \augusto_map_csv_rows:Nn #1 {#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand \IterateCSVCols { m +m }
  { \augusto_map_csv_cols:Nn #1 {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\ReadCSV{project.csv}\project

Resources for the first task from Work Package \project{task1.1, wp}
are \project{task1.1, resources} USD

\begin{tabular}{*4c}
\IterateCSVCols \project { & #1 } \\
\IterateCSVRows \project
  {%
    #1
    \IterateCSVCols \project
      { & \project{#1,##1} }
    \\
  }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I loop through `\project` to build a table with custom row?

Comment: It seems there is a glitch. If a value is missing in a source csv file, the command `\project{id,col}` will grab and display the value of the next row.

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev Bug fixed (replaced `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn`, which discards empty items, by `\seq_set_split:Nnn`).  I added iterator functions `\IterateCSVRows` and `\IterateCSVCols` and and example of how to rebuild the CSV as a table

Comment: Thank you for your changes. It works now. One more question. While iterating through project lines I use `str_if_eq:nnTF`, but it always executes False branch: `\str_if_eq:nnTF {\project{#1,resources}} {2k} {small}{big}`. I think it is related to expanding. How can I use string comparison?

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev Use `\str_if_eq:eeTF` to expand the arguments

Comment: Thanks again! It works.